# Anchor links reload the page

Tags: php, html

I am building a static page in `.php` file with url http://example.com/support/test and after clicking on this link page is reloaded but does not scroll to the needed section. Here is the example code snippet:

```
<ul class="links">
    <li>
        <a href="#first">First</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#second">Second</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<section>
    <h3 id="first">First</h3>
</section>

<section>
    <h3 id="second">Second</h3>
</section>
```

But instead of scrolling to the id browser reload the page with a link like that http://example.com/#first.
What can be the problem and how can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: I had the same issue. In my case this was happening because of a `<base/>` tag. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76013460/relative-uri-fragment-link-points-to-homepage-instead-of-the-same-page

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. Link href should look like `/support/test/#first`

Answer (score 0):

Becuase you dont have enough scroll in page, so you are seeing all in one page. You can check with scroll like:

```
<ul class="links">
    <li>
        <a href="#first">First</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#second">Second</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<section>
    <h3 id="first" style="height: 900px;">First</h3>
</section>

<section>
    <h3 id="second" style="height: 900px;">Second</h3>
</section>
```

Comment: no, this is a dummy example. I have a lot of content on this page. But I tried your suggestion and result the same

Comment: @YaroslavSaenko Is there enough content for page scroll?

Comment: yes, more than enough. I provide an example, but not the real content

Comment: @YaroslavSaenko try like:
<ul class="links">
    <li>
        <a href="?#first">First</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="?#second">Second</a>
    </li>
</ul>

Comment: it always redirect to the main page after reload :-(