# Relative URI fragment link points to homepage instead of the same page?

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

### What I tried

On `page.html`:

```
<a href="#top">#top</a>
```

I then open `page.html` in both Firefox and Chrome, right-click the link and choose *Copy Link Address*.

### What I got

```
example.com/#top
```

### What I expected to get

```
example.com/page.html#top
```

I remember from my early days working with HTML, and I'm reading [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#linking_to_an_element_on_the_same_page) now, that relative URI fragment anchors (`#something`) should point to the same page the browser is at (and clicking these links shouldn't reload the page). This is in line with the behaviour I get from this test snippet as well:

```html
<a href="#top">#top</a>
```

The above snippet links to `https://stacksnippets.net/js#top`, not `https://stacksnippets.net/#top`, meaning it works as expected.

I found another question having the same issue: [Anchor links reload the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70109460/anchor-links-reload-the-page). The guy there ends up pointing to `/support/test/#first`, explicitly telling the browser to point to the same page. That is likely to be my last resort as well, but first I want to see if I can make the standard behaviour work.

So why is this happening? If there's something else going on my page, how do I debug and where do I look? Are there any common reasons for this behaviour, e.g. maybe some Bootstrap plugin is known to be interfering?

The page where this happens is using jQuery and Bootstrap only.

**UPDATE**: I removed all the scripts and stylesheets from the page, still getting the issue. So this is not jQuery or Bootstrap interfering.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
<base href="https://example.com"/>
```

It was in the `<head></head>` of the document. If I delete this [`<base/>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) live using *Web Developer Tools* → *Inspector*, it fixes the relative URL immediately, without any page reload even.